# SVG Dimensions based on its Children

Tags: jquery, svg

I'm dabbling in using jQuery to create SVGs, paths, and lines dynamically. I have the SVG and the paths/lines appearing as expected, but I'm running into an issue when the paths/lines are really tall. I'd want to be able to scroll up and down to see the rest of the SVG, but I would have to set the height and width of the SVG to do that. The problem is, I may not know what the height should be at any given time.

I've tried using 100% or even 100vh for the height property of the SVG, but neither of them help if the graphic is taller than the given area.

Is there a way to have the SVG expand (not scale) based on the height of its contents?

Comment: There is no automatic way if that's what you mean.  But you are creating the contents of the SVG yourself, so why can't you keep track of the Y coordinates and update the SVG `height` as you go?

Comment: Hi Paul. It's a fair point. I think I would have to find the highest values for both the y and x ending points and extrapolate from there. I was hoping the SVG would be more flexible. Since this is the same way we place absolute positioned elements, it makes sense that we would have to hard code the parent element's dimensions.